# The effect of putting sudo -i command in /etc/fstab

Tags: ssh, sudo, fstab

I have a computer (computer A) which only can be accessed by `ssh` from another computer (computer B) within internal network.

```
ssh username@10.**.**.**
```

FYI, I do not activate root account in computer A.

Later on, when I already login to the computer A, I modify the `/etc/fstab` file by adding `sudo -i` as additional line in it.

Finally, I reboot the computer A.
Several minutes later, I try to login to computer A again but I can not.

Is it related to my modification or there is internal network down at the moment?
Thanks

Comment: sorry care to explaing /etc/fstab + sudo -i? fstab is for mounting partitions, not for ssh.

Comment: I try to mount a directory. I put the `mount` command in the /etc/fstab

Comment: However it stated that only root can do that action

Comment: So I decide to put `sudo -i` in the `/etc/fstab`

Comment: Is that the reason why later on I can not access computer A?

Comment: You don't put commands in the `fstab`. That file is just a list of mounts which should be automounted (or not). The `mountall` command runs as root when you boot, so you don't have to care about `sudo`. If you put `sudo -i` into `fstab` then the `mountall` command likely can't parse that file because of that syntax error. So yes, this is your problem.

Comment: @falconer, OK I should use `mountall` command instead. However right now I can't login to computer A. Is that because I put `sudo -i` on the `/etc/fstab` ? Or because the computer is down so that I should contact the administrator

Comment: @SantosaSandy No, you don't have to use `mountall`, the system uses it when it boots up to mount everything which is listen in `fstab`. I write an answer to clear this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't put commands in the `fstab`. That file is just a list of mounts which should be automounted (or not). The `mountall` command runs as root when you boot, and mounts everything which is listed in the `fstab`. (Except those mounts which have the `noauto` options set in `fstab`, those ones are not automounted.)  So you don't have to care about `sudo`.

If you put `sudo -i` into `fstab` then the `mountall` command likely can't parse that file because of that syntax error: The `mountall` command is trying to mount the `sudo -i` drive or something more wrong. So yes, this is your problem.

You rebooted your computer with a syntax error in `fstab`. As the system boots, it calls `mountall` to mount the listed things from `fstab`. `mountall` reaches that `sudo -i` line which he doesn't know what to do with. Your system is likely stuck at this point and waiting for interaction on what to do.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. So now my computer is stuck and can not be accessed. It means a fatal command to put `sudo -i` in the `/etc/fstab`

Comment: Do you have any suggestion to remove `sudo -i` command from `/etc/fstab` so I can access my computer again, please?

Comment: @SantosaSandy Do you have local access to your computer or only remote?

Comment: remote access using `ssh username@10.**.**.**`

Comment: @SantosaSandy Then you can't do it. You need local access to the computer to interact with the machine on how to continue the boot, or to correct the `fstab` from a live environment. But I put this question in chat if anyone knows a remote method, but I think it is totally impossible.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I just think, what I can do is using my back up to reinstall the machine. But that is the last option.

Comment: @SantosaSandy Yes, you need local access to the machine to solve this. Or do that reinstall as you said.